# How can I work out and display the dB(SPL) level in a JS application?

Tags: javascript, audio, decibel

I have got the input of the microphone with Tone.JS library and I'm able to switch it on and off using a checkbox. I would like to calculate the decibel level and then display it on the screen in real-time.

Has anyone got any pointers for this, like code snippets or websites that could help me?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Alfie

Comment: Are you able to add an Analyser Node from the web audio API to the output of Tone.js?
If not does the library provide access to one? If so I have an answer.

Comment: Note that you aren't going to be able to compute dB SPL unless you do callibration, or, say, have precalibrated your app for a specific device.

Comment: @DavidSherman Thanks for your reply, I've managed to find in the Tone.js library a gainToDb function so i'll be using this, then calibrating to dB(A).

Comment: @Linuxios Thanks for your reply also, I think I will aim to play a tone through the speakers and calibrate to that.